# How to disable a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been creating a few Multibranch Pipeline projects in Jenkins and now

I've "upgraded" to use a GitHub Organization project.

How do I disable the old Multibranch Pipeline projects?
I don't see any Disable button anywhere.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Since I can't add a screenshot to a reply, I'm editing my question to include the screenshot to show I have the latest version of the Pipeline Plugin installed, 2.16:

[image]

Comment: So it looks like disabling a Jenkins multibranch pipeline project is not possible. However, specific branches can be disabled in Project > Configure > Branch Sources > Exception.

Comment: Go into the configuration page for the multi branch pipeline. Under the Branch Sources, in the Properties section, add a property, and select "Suppress automatic SCM triggering".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of the Pipeline Job plugin *(I am using version 2.25 from Sep 5, 2018)* and you do not see the disable option, then you can still disable the job by appending `/disable` to the URL of the job.

Source:

> You would need to be logged in as a user who has access to
>   write/configure builds. And if the build is Pipeline Multibranch you
>   still won't see the disable button. If that's the case, you can append
>   `/disable` to the project URL to disable it.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27299?focusedCommentId=336904&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-336904

Comment: how do i re-enable this job back again?

Comment: Dunno, have you tried to append `/enable` to the project URL?

Answer (score 27):

Append `/disable` to the end of Job URL. Then Jenkins will redirect you to a page where you can `Post`. Same applies for `/enable` too

[image]

Comment: if it throws permission error then just scan the project and it will enable all the branches.

Comment: This just repeats my answer from 2018. Downvoting.

Answer (score 13):

Go into the configuration page for the multi branch pipeline. Under the Branch Sources, in the Properties section, add a property, and select "Suppress automatic SCM triggering".

Comment: useful... but looks like that is deprecated.  Wasn't able to find when it will be actually removed.

Comment: In 2.121 that makes it so that a scan for updating which branches exist will not trigger a build when it finds a new branch

Answer (score 1):

The Multibranch plugin I installed is 2.21. No "Disable" option is available (at least I didn't see it). I did the following to disable the multibranch pipeline:
Open the pipeline -> **Configure** -> uncheck *Periodically if not otherwise run* under **Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers**

Answer (score -1):

You are not seeing the disable option may be because you are using an older version of pipeline job plugin. The feature to disable job was added in version 2.11 released in May 2017. Refer [change log](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Job+Plugin) of pipeline job plugin and try updating your plugin to latest.

For multi branch pipeline specific branches can be disabled in Project > Configure > Branch Sources > Exception

Comment: I am using Pipeline Job plugin version 2.25 (Sep 5, 2018) and I cannot disable a pipeline job. I used "Suppress automatic SCM triggering" instead.